# Who can participate in Casper?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

From what I understand, non-validators will feel benefits from the change to casper. However, is it only validators that can actually participate in Casper? Is it correct that if you have etehreum in your wallet, it does **not** increase because of age or something else?

That the only ones participating in the Proof of stake system is only the validators?

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The validators are the ones running the network, so they're the ones that get rewarded with interest. If everyone got interest, then there would essentially be no interest at all, and validators would have no reason to run the network.