# How does interest work in casper?

Tags: casper, reward, block-reward

Based on this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37419/24310

How does interest work with casper? Is it correct to describe what the validators receive as interest?

Answer (score 2):

Answering a question that links to my own answer on *another* question, ha!

So there are really two flavors of Casper, one of which is hybrid PoS/PoW and the other is full Pos.

Casper FFG (Friendly Finality Gadget): This is the hybrid that runs PoS as a contract on top of the existing PoW system in order to achieve finality so block history revision is less effective. In this system, the economics (you can read the details [here](https://github.com/ethereum/research/blob/master/papers/casper-economics/casper_economics_basic.pdf)) work out to **pretty accurately be called *interest***. Essentially, there exists a global interest based on how the whole system is running, and a per-validator interest based on how each actor is running. All validators are paid a percentage based on the global/per-validator rates on a per-epoch (50 blocks) for voting.

Casper TFG (The Friendly Ghost): Also often called CBC (Correct by Construction), but that's actually a family of Casper protocols that it belongs in. The economics of this are either not flushed out or just not published yet AFAIK, but it'll likely work on a similar percentage basis based on how well the system is running and how well each validator is running. More on the mechanics, but not really the economics, can be read [here](https://github.com/ethereum/research/blob/master/papers/CasperTFG/CasperTFG.pdf)